# Concat rows with the same user

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have the query:

```
SELECT e.id_taxe
     , u.nm_user
     , dt_taxe
     , SUM(e.vl_taxe) as vl_taxe
FROM taxe as e 
  JOIN user as u 
    ON u.id_user = e.id_user 
WHERE id_enterprise = 86 
   AND dt_taxe BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
   AND lg_cancel = 0 
 GROUP 
    BY e.dt_taxe
     , e.id_user 
 ORDER 
    BY e.id_user
     , e.dt_taxe
```

As result, I have:

```
id_taxe     nm_user   dt_taxe      vl_taxe
728         Maria     2017-01-01   17091.07048034668
727         Maria     2017-02-01   14091.07048034668
721         Maria     2017-03-01   1021.07048034668
731         Pedro     2017-01-01   16353.569854736328
732         Pedro     2017-02-01   6353.56231239
```

How I can concat the rows, to get the result:

```
id_taxe     nm_user   dt_taxe      vl_taxe
728         Maria     2017-01-01   17091.07048034668 , 
                      2017-02-01   14091.07048034668,
                      2017-03-01   1021.07048034668
731         Pedro     2017-01-01   16353.569854736328,
                      2017-02-01   6353.56231239
```

Comment: How do you want to determine the ID_Taxe to display?  is it the ID_Taxe associated to the lowest DT_Taxe?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application level code

Answer (score 0):

With a database like PostgreSQL this could be done with window functions but MySQL has no support for window functions so you cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is usually best done at the application layer.  Your result set is not very SQLish, because ordering is *very* important.

However, you can do this with variables:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN id_taxe END) as id_taxe,
       (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN nm_user END) as num_user,
       dt_taxe, vl_taxe
FROM (SELECT eu.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = e.id_user, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := e.id_user, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT e.id_taxe, u.nm_user, e.dt_taxe, SUM(e.vl_taxe) as vl_taxe
            FROM taxe e INNER JOIN
                 user u 
                 ON u.id_user = e.id_user 
            WHERE id_enterprise = 86 AND
                  dt_taxe BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31' AND
                  lg_cancel = 0
            GROUP BY e.dt_taxe, e.id_user
           ) eu CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @i := -1, @rn := 0)
      ORDER BY id_user, dt_taxe
     ) eu;
```